# Stop the stretch of HTML select in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've been trying unsuccessfully to set an HTML "select" field size in Bootstrap 3(latest) to normal (not 100% width). Do you know an elegant way of doing this, without hacks like tables around fields. 
I also don't want to put a select field in a bootstrap column since then I'll have indent due to borders.
Custom styles with specific sizes is also not pretty in my opinion, because all I want is for the field to be only as long as the longest content (default behavior of a select)

Perhaps there is a really easy way to circumvent this since Bootstrap decided to make all selects (using form-control class) stretch all the way, looking forward to your illuminating suggestions )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting the width to auto or initial?

```
width: auto;
```

or

```
width:initial;
```

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_width.asp

Comment: Thanks this works, and I can just add select.form-control in order to preserve the other fields from shrinking

Answer (score 0):

```
select
{
    width: auto;
    width: inherit;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Dean was first though that's why I accepted his.